# Получить картинку и часть текста из html

Tags: php, html, регулярные-выражения, dom

Необходимо регулярное выражение, для получения первой картинки из статьи и куска текста из 300 знаков, для формирования анонса статьи.

Вот такая, к примеру статейка:

```
$content = '<img src="files/1.jpg" alt="" width="200px" />
<img src="files/2.jpg" alt="" width="200px" />
<img src="files/3.jpg" alt="" width="200px" />
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>';
```

Нужно чтобы, выводило только скажем:

```
$content = '<img src="files/1.jpg" alt="" width="200px" />
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua...</p>';
```

Очень желательно, чтобы выводило уже с html-тегами и если обрезается текст, то ставилось <...> и закрывающий тег.

Очень надеюсь на помощь, я совсем начинающий кодер.

Вот код, но он выводит только картинку:

```
while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) {

    preg_match('/<img.+src=[\'"](?P<src>.+?)[\'"].*>/i', $row['content'], $image);

    echo 'id: ' . $row['id'] . '<br /> Дата и время: ' . $row['datetime'] . '<br /> Заголовок: ' . $row['title'] . '<br /> Категория: <a href="?category=' . $row['category'] . '">' . $row['category'] . '</a><br /> Контент: ' . $image['src'] . '<br />
        <a href="?article=' . $row['id'] . '">Читать</a>
        <br />-------------------------------------------------<br />';
}
```

Comment: За вас написать код ? вы опубликуйте вариант кода где у вас не получилось, или есть ошибка в коде. И вообще регулярные выражения не предназначены для парсинга html, посмотрите в сторону специализированных библиотек http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net

Comment: Добавил в вопрос

Comment: @Linne, `src="files/1.jpg"` все цифры идут по порядку всегда?

Comment: Нет, это для примера просто :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы фанат велосипедов, то можно и так :)

```
preg_match('~<img.+/>\n?~', $content, $matches);

$text = preg_replace_callback('~<p>(.+)</p>~', function ($m) {
    return '<p>'.substr($m[1], 0, strpos($m[1], ' ', 300)).'...</p>'; 
}, preg_replace('~<img.+\n~', '', $content));

echo $matches[0] . $text;
```

Comment: :))))))))))))))

Comment: А картинка не выводится(

Comment: Не работает :) $img = preg_replace('~(?!(^(<img.*/>)))<img.*\n~', '', $row['content']);

  $text = preg_replace_callback('~<p>(.+)</p>~', function ($m) {
      return '<p>'.substr($m[1], 0, strpos($m[1], ' ', 300)).'...</p>'; 
  }, $text);
  
  $output = $img . $text;

Comment: @Linne, обновил, попробуйте.

Answer (score 2):

Лучшая регулярка для подобной работы - нормальный парсер DOM.

```
$content = '<img src="files/1.jpg" alt="" width="200px" />
<img src="files/2.jpg" alt="" width="200px" />
<img src="files/3.jpg" alt="" width="200px" />
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>';

$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($content);
$firstImage = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0);
$src = $firstImage->attributes->getNamedItem('src')->nodeValue;
echo <<<IMG
<img src="{$src}" />
IMG;

$text = $dom->textContent;
$trunc300 = substr($text, 0, strpos($text, ' ', 300));
echo <<<HTML
<p>
  {$trunc300}
</p>
HTML;
```

Answer (score 1):

Зачем сразу регулярка?

Можно вот таким вот образом к примеру

```
$content = '<img src="files/1.jpg" alt="" width="200px" />
<img src="files/2.jpg" alt="" width="200px" />
<img src="files/3.jpg" alt="" width="200px" />
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($content);
$imgs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
$src = $imgs[0]->getAttribute('src');
$width = $imgs[0]->getAttribute('width');
echo "<img src=\"$src\" width=\"$width\">";
```

Comment: Зато у меня с текстом))

Comment: @vp_arth он позже добавил про текст=)

Answer (score 1):

Согласен с предыдущими отвечающими - не используйте регулярки для разбора html.

Хочу добавить только одно: регулярные выражения - это не волшебная палочка, и не серебряная пуля. регулярные выражения - обычный конечный автомат, программа которая выделяет память для хранения промежуточных итогов, выполняет действия в циклах, иногда даже рекурсию применяет.

Чем сложнее будет регулярное выражение, тем дольше будет работать и больше жрать памяти.

Поэтому (если уж так уперлось в регулярное выражение и совсем никак нельзя работать с DOM) зачастую лучше применить несколько проходов. В вашем случае, первым проходом лучше найти текст, начиная от изображения до текста включительно. А вторым проходом выкинуть из промежуточного результата лишнее.

Comment: «первым проходом лучше найти текст, начиная от изображения до текста включительно. А вторым проходом выкинуть из промежуточного результата лишнее.» — б-же, как же всё сложно-то…

Comment: разве )))) "Лучшая регулярка для подобной работы - нормальный парсер DOM."

Comment: Просто хочется минимум кода и методов, минимализьму хочется)

Comment: "решил проблему с помощью регулярных выражений? теперь у тебя две проблемы". Сложные регулярки понимать, отлаживать и модифицировать намного сложнее, чем десяток строк кода. Бойтесь своих желаний. Лучше желайте не "минимума кода", а "минимума усилий" по поддержке этого кода.

Comment: и еще про минимум кода: есть [CodeGolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf). Там побеждает код с меньшим количеством символов. очень интересно народ изворачивается, чтобы минимизировать свой код. Но я врагу не пожелаю встретить подобное решение в боевом проекте.